# Camel load balancing with jdbc endpoint

Tags: jdbc, apache-camel

Can anyone explain how to use camel load balancing with jdbc endpoint?
If my first db is down it need to pick second db automatically.

My Route builder:

```
        from("direct:jdbcisuserexists").setBody(simple("${body}"))
            .loadBalance()
            .failover()
            .to("jdbc:dataSource?resetAutoCommit=false&outputType=SelectList","jdbc:dataSource1?resetAutoCommit=false&outputType=SelectList");
```

Comment: Dont do this on the camel. Hot fail over/ high availability should be configured for the database i.e. on MSSQL they could be in a mirror set. You point to one address and this is handled transparently. Start by getting your architecture into a HA solution then move onto the other details.

Comment: @Namphibian Thanks for your comment. But we are using nosql(Cassandra database) in which load balancing is not advisable. so we trying it in camel.

Comment: My suggestion then would be to create two routes. If the first one fails send the message to the second one and then process there. I will see if I can post an answer around it.

Comment: @Namphibian Thanks again. The point you are suggesting is not to use loadbalance for camel jdbc endpoints right? ok. we will try with two different route and get back with the results. It would be most appreciated if you post the answer you found. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
from("direct:jdbcisuserexists")
    .setBody(simple("${body}"))
    .loadBalance().failover()
        .to("jdbc:dataSource?resetAutoCommit=false&outputType=SelectList")
        .to("jdbc:dataSource1?resetAutoCommit=false&outputType=SelectList")
    .end();
```

This should work, though it feels a bit over-broad. The `failover()` DSL element will work on all exceptions. You can narrow this down to a particular exception, such as via `failover(SQLException.class)`, but there is no guarantee that this exception is a caused by a database outage (it could be something in your SQL syntax).

A better alternative (as implied by @Namphibian) would be to have two routes, each calling its own JDBC endpoint. Each route could be selective about checking that the SQLException was actually caused by an outage (such as by checking the error message for DB-specific fault codes). To fall back to a second database on failure you could use a dynamic router (https://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html).